Looking for a SF book about an initially invisible and radioactive spacecraft landing in America, but also Russia
Apologies for my scatterbrained vagueness, but this is my first time doing something like this.
Back in high-school in the mid 2010's, I picked up a sci-fi book from the library that had a 70's sort of cover and browned pages, being white and orange with a suitably retro font, although I don't really remember it well.  I took it out and read the whole thing, and I remember it being a great read, even though I've since forgotten most of it. I'm going to try and summarise it to track to down again, as well as pick out more specific plot points.
It started with an object approaching Earth at a rapid speed causing panic in the US.  There was section where it re-entered, then it crashed into the US somewhere. The army then closed in, cordoned it off, and then found that electronic devices didn't function in the area.
Said spacecraft was invisible but transmitted EM radiation that was slowly decreasing and or increasing in wavelength. I think whatever scientist that came to the site figured this out because some redneck was around when it crashed had then gotten radiation sunburn, as well as the obvious.
One of the oddly specific sections I remember was about army trucks with glowplugs and magnetos being brought in to enter the zone, rather than ones with sparkplugs to get around this electronic limiting. The probe also visually, when it appears, was a black pyramid (I think) and octopodal robot that got killed (I think) and an investigator getting pissed about getting his car scratched because they couldn't  get the paint redone the way it was done in the factory, which did happen in the book which strikes me for its specificity.
The cold war angle also came in when it's  found out the Soviets had an identical probe crash thing, and the named the 'the commissar' (I think), and that there were several other probe-y things, then I can't really remember. I'm fairly certain people started to become psychic towards the ending chapters.
I apologise if this is rambling and unhelpful, but I really just want to find this book and track it down to own and have, and read again to put it back into the banks of my memory. If this description puts an image in your head, don't be afraid to post an answer.

Did the object cause electrical interference that expanded in stages?

Possibly! It seems like a reasonable element but I'm not certain, if my tone wasn't clear.

It's possible you're recalling Patrick Tilley's Fade-Out (1975), which matches the Cold War setting and black pyramidal alien craft landing in the U.S., the U.S.S.R. and other places.
In Fade-Out, an alien ship (the U.S. only observes one initially) temporarily wipes out all shortwave radio broadcasts and radars when it enters Earth orbit.  After orbiting for a couple of days, visible to radar but completely black in optical wavelengths, it lands in Crow Ridge, Montana (we discover later at least one more ship has landed in Kazakhstan as well) and buries itself in the ground.
Locals find a 1.1km (0.69mi) radius zone where electrical devices are knocked out by current surges from an extremely strong alternating magnetic field.  The ship moves underground, then surfaces a spherical section.  Periodically the zone of electrical disruption expands by a factor of ten: next 11km, then 110km...
By examining disruptions to the Earth's magnetic field they determine there are 6 of these locations that are reshaping the Earth's magnetic field, although 4 of them are in the ocean.
The alien craft ("Crusoe") changes into the shape of a 60-foot tall (smooth) black pyramid and continues to grow by throwing out blocks horizontally in the cardinal directions; these blocks are described as having steps, though.
The zone of effect expands to cover the entire world, and humanity is faced with trying to retain civilization without the benefit of electricity or anything electrical.

I don't know quite how you did it, but this is it. Well, the cover and back matches on a search, so this seems to be the book I forgot, the plot seems to fill the mental gaps too. Thank you for the prompt answer, Wow!

@VermouthOnTheRocks It was fairly easy for me because I've identified this book before. :D

@DavidW Then the correct approach would've been to mark this question as a duplicate of the other one.

@IanKemp That's not site policy for [tag:story-identification]; only confirmed answers are marked as duplicate.
